# Apache connections from lan or localhost on external IP hang

Tags: apache-http-server

I have a Virtualmin installation on an Ubuntu box behind a router. My server runs on `192.168.1.220`, outside of the DHCP range and my external IP address, let's say it's `123.123.123`. I've setup port-forward on port 80 (tcp) and 53 (tcp/udp) among others. I have a couple of nameservers and a domain hosted on this box, let's say example.com that works like a charm from remote connections (this is not my first server).

However, when I try to connect to the server from localhost or lan using `http://example.com` ( or `http://123.123.123.123`), it connects and awaits server response.. and never stops. No disconnects, no nothing.

The only difference that I notice would be that the previous boxes run Apache 2.2 and this one has Apache 2.4.

```
root@ns1:~# wget example.com
--2014-12-17 11:24:05--  http://example.com/
Resolving example.com (example.com)... 123.123.123.123
Connecting to example.com example.com)|123.123.123.123|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
```

So, after a while I've stopped it.
The hit gets logged in the apache access_log, but no error in the error_log.

```
123.123.123.123 - - [17/Dec/2014:11:37:57 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 435 "-" "Wget/1.15 (linux-gnu)"
```

And on the lan IP:

```
root@ns1:~# wget 192.168.1.220
--2014-12-17 11:33:58--  http://192.168.1.220/
Connecting to 192.168.1.220:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://192.168.1.220/ro/ [following]
--2014-12-17 11:33:58--  http://192.168.1.220/ro/
Reusing existing connection to 192.168.1.220:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html.2’
```

NOTE that the redirect is on purpose, the website has intl for Romanian, thus the 302 redirection.

I don't even know what config file to put here. Ask for any...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I still have this problem... Bump...